# Cordova Facebook plugin - cannot show dialog

Tags: facebook, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-facebook

I'm trying the basic example seen here : [Facebook4 plugin](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4#show-a-dialog)

```
facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog({
    method: "send",
    caption: "Check this out.",
    link: "http://example.com",
    description: "The site I told you about",
    picture: "http://example.com/image.png"
}, function(result) {
    // Success!
    $timeout(function () {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    });
    console.log("success", result);
}, function(err) {
    // An error occured. Show a message to the user
    $timeout(function () {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    });
    console.log("error - ", err);
});
```

And I get this error message :

```
Cannot show dialog
```

I'm really not sure what's going on... And looking for a long time now without making any progress. Any help ?

I don't think it's linked but the permissions asked on login are

```
["public_profile", "email", "user_birthday"]
```

Thanks !

Comment: did you fix this issue i'm also facing a this problem, please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: I ended up using `https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin` for Facebook also, since it was the simplest thing to do and I didn't want to lose too much time on this

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy Belolo , i need also social login action inside the app like facebook, twitter and google.
Thanks in advance